# Java Reminder Scheduler

Tags: java, postgresql

How to make my java class to continuously read the database in a loop and then send reminders through java mail if there is an entry in the database.

For example,
I have a table called "jobs" which has the columns job_id, epoch_time, email_id.
Here when the epoch_time equals current time, I have to send mail to email_id.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add code you've tried already

Comment: you should send email while saving schedule to DB.

Comment: No, I haven't written code yet. I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: @parladneupane I have to send mail only at that saved epoch time

Comment: You should always show your attempt with your question. If you are totally lost before asking, then you haven't searched enough. Voting to close as too broad.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Can you give me a link for the answer to this question. It would be helpful.

Comment: then you should call it after data has been saved , and get data from database. Try some code , java mail has a make so much easy send email.

Answer (score 0):

You can use trigger to call a JAVA program you want. Say, you can call a program in AFTER INSERT or BEFORE INSERT. Refer https://docs.oracle.com/database/122/JJDEV/calling-Java-from-database-triggers.htm#JJDEV13286. Hope this suits your scenario.

Comment: I see, this trigger happens only when a DML operation is done. This is not the case because it should trigger when current time crosses epoch time saved in db.

Answer (score 0):

1. You Can do it with extending TimerTask to your class. For example [Read More about Java TimerTask](https://www.journaldev.com/1050/java-timer-timertask-example)
2. Another option is Using Java Timer. Using scheduling method you can schedule your specific task. [Example with Java Timer](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/timer_schedule_period.htm)